# Not enough values to unpack error in the pipeline

Tags: python, function, scikit-learn, pipeline

I have these two cells of code (blatantly copied from an online article and modified a bit) that would compare different model performances:

```
def create_pipe(clf):
    
        column_trans = ColumnTransformer(
            [
                ('SimpleImputer', SimpleImputer(strategy ='constant', fill_value = 'unanswered'), categorical_cols.columns),
                ('KNNImputer', KNNImputer(missing_values=np.nan, n_neighbors=17), numeric_cols.columns),
                ('enc', OneHotEncoder(sparse = False, drop=None), list(range(len(categorical_cols.columns)))),
                ('standard_scaler', MinMaxScaler()),
                ('variance', VarianceThreshold(threshold=(.95 * (1 - .95))))
            ],
            remainder='passthrough')
    
        pipeline = Pipeline([('prep',column_trans),
                             ('clf', clf)])
    
        return pipeline
```

and

```
models = {'RFG' : RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42),
          'LogReg' : LogisticRegression(random_state=42)
          }

for name, model, in models.items():
    clf = model
    pipeline = create_pipe(clf)
    scores = cross_val_score(pipeline, 
                             X, 
                             y, 
                             scoring='f1_macro', 
                             cv=3, 
                             n_jobs=1, 
                             error_score='raise')
    print(name, ': Mean f1 Macro: %.3f and Standard Deviation: (%.3f)' % (np.mean(scores), np.std(scores)))
```

But when running the second one, I get the following error for the "scores = cross_val_score(pipeline [...]":

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

What so obvious am I missing here? Is the data structure to blame?

Comment: remove the last comma in `for name, model, in models.items():` -> `for name, model in models.items():`

Comment: @ConstantinGuidon I don't think it's that... `for k, v, in somedict.items():` works for me.  Can you show more of the traceback?  Seems like the error is coming from inside `cross_val_score` function somewhere

Comment: Good catch and corrected, but still the same error.<br/>
Last traceback points to this:<br/>
`File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py:324, in ColumnTransformer._validate_transformers(self)
    321 if not self.transformers:
    322     return
--> 324 names, transformers, _ = zip(*self.transformers)
    326 # validate names
    327 self._validate_names(names)`

Comment: Shoud the data be already preformatted to int only before going into pipeline? My dataframe has both int and str.

Comment: This error disappears when I eliminate MinMaxScaler() from the fundtion but then it throws "could not convert string to float:".

Comment: You're not specifying which columns you're applying `'standard_scaler'` and `'variance'` transformers to in your [`ColumnTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) instance

Comment: ColumnTransformer takes a list of transformers, which are of type: List of (name, transformer, columns). But, in "standard_scaler" and "variance", you didn't specify "columns". Doc: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html?highlight=columntrans#sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer

Comment: Didn't see the comment made by @amiola

Comment: @amiola - thank you! It throws "could not convert string to float" now, but the original issue is solved.